# path and operator and wild card searches

Tags: xpath

Have many xmlfiles like this whose structure is not same and may vary.

```
<ratings>
  <rating>
    <agency>SP</agency>
    <provider>SP</provider>
    <type>LONG TERM</type>
    <currencyType>LOCAL</currencyType>
    <description>SP Standard LT LC rating</description>
    <crating by = "Moodys">
        <code>BBB+</code>
    </crating>
    <crating by = "S&P">
        <code>AAA-</code>
    </crating>
    <date>2011-09-07</date>
  </rating>
</ratings>
```

I would like to find all xml documents that have a text of **BBB+ and AAA-**
Since the **xml structures vary** i have to resort to wild cards and cannot rely on 
element names any ideas how would i do this please.

My try is but it doesnt work

```
//*[. = "BBB+" and . = "AAA-"]
```

If i don't use the "and" it works but then it wouldn't meet my criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
/*[//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'AAA-'] and //*[normalize-space(text()) = 'BBB+']]
```

That will return element if there are "*text of **BBB+ and AAA-***", and return nothing/null otherwise. In addition to this, check answer from @Robin, it contains explanation and good advice to consider.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*: This actually answers the case where you want only one criteria met, ie there's at least one node with the text 'AAA-' or 'BBB+'

You can use

```
//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'AAA-' or normalize-space(text()) = 'BBB+']
```

which will return the node where the text is found. You can directly put a condition on the `text()` attribute, and the `normalize-space` function trims the text from trailing whitespaces.

This will obviously be quite slow as it requires to check all nodes. If you can change the `*` into a `code`, this would greatly increase performance.

Comment: I want to get the result when both the conditions are met.In your case if i change 'BBB+' to something else even then i get the result which is not what i want .Apologies if this wasn't clear

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't get that. @har07's answer is probably closer to what you want to do then! I'll update my "answer" accordingly.